# Laravel Horizon with Sail and Octane - Command "horizon:supervisor" is not defined

Tags: laravel

i used Laravel 9 with sail and octane

when I run the command "sail artisan horizon" it doesn't start the supervisors

i run "horizon:install" then

the config/horizon is default config by laravel

in my .env i put QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis

I can run the queues only with the command "sail artisan horizon:work"

the command "sail artisan horizon" fail with Command "horizon:supervisor" is not defined.

then i try see the supervisors with "sail artisan horizon:supervisors" but this shows the message "No supervisors are running."

supervisors config in config/horizon

```
'defaults' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'connection' => 'redis',
        'queue' => ['default'],
        'balance' => 'auto',
        'maxProcesses' => 1,
        'maxTime' => 0,
        'maxJobs' => 0,
        'memory' => 128,
        'tries' => 1,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'nice' => 0,
    ],
],

'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
        ],
    ],

    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'maxProcesses' => 3,
        ],
    ],
],
```

see images for better understanding

[horizon view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezh2x.png)

[horizon command linde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oEQQ.png)

[horizon config supervisors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5TJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

After many commands it was not discovered why the commands are not being recognized by sail, but that I made the Provider not recognizing when the command was run in console.

This fact I just inserted after the commands in the Provider controlled it ($this->app->runningInConsole()) and it worked normally

Inside App/Providers/HorizonServiceProvider, located inside boot

```
$this->commands([
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\ClearCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\ContinueCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\ContinueSupervisorCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\ForgetFailedCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\HorizonCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\InstallCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\ListCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\PauseCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\PauseSupervisorCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\PublishCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\PurgeCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\StatusCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\SupervisorCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\SupervisorsCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\TerminateCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\TimeoutCommand::class,
        \Laravel\Horizon\Console\WorkCommand::class,
    ]);
```